# NSObject returns nothing XCode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, ios-simulator, nsobject

I moved my app to XCode 6 and found this problem. I have NSObject and it stopped returning objects when initialized, I use XCode 6 iPhone 6 Simulator.
My .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface RBGAlpha : NSObject{
    NSString *red;
    NSString *blue;
    NSString *green;
    NSString *alpha;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *red;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *blue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *green;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *alpha;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)r  bl:(NSString *)b  gr:(NSString *)g  al:(NSString *)a;
@end
```

my .m file

```
#import "RBGAlpha.h"
@implementation RBGAlpha
@synthesize red,blue,green,alpha;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)r bl:(NSString *)b  gr:(NSString *)g  al:(NSString *)a{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.red = r;
        self.blue = b;
        self.green = g;
        self.alpha = a;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I use something like this in viewDidLoad method to create my objects:

```
RBGAlpha *tmpObj=[[RBGAlpha alloc] initWithName:@"0.01" bl:@"0.01" gr:@"0.01" al:@"1.00"];
```

However, while running the app in Simulator iPhone 6 this returns nothing
[image]

Has anybody dealt with that kind of problem?

Comment: NSLog the value or use `po tmpObj` in the console.  The debugger variable display facilities have always been flaky and have become moreso with recent Xcode versions.

Comment: and great thanks to that one who -1 me for asking a question, I would understand -1 for giving an answer, but is not this the place to ask questions?

Comment: @Hot Licks po tmpObj returns only that 0x786.. no actual values

Comment: Well, RGBAlpha appears to be your class.  How did you implement `description`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're being mislead. There is indeed a value, that is what `0x786...` in the value field means.

Summary saying 0 objects is confusing. I cannot understand why it would say that, but I bet if you typed `po tmpObj` into LLDB it would not return `nil` but the address showing next to "Value".

If you want to see something more interesting from the Xcode debugger consider implementing [`debugQuickLookObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/CustomClassDisplay_in_QuickLook/CH01-quick_look_for_custom_objects/CH01-quick_look_for_custom_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014001-CH2-SW2).

On a side note, you can omit the definition of your instances variables in

```
@interface RBGAlpha : NSObject{
    NSString *red;
    NSString *blue;
    NSString *green;
    NSString *alpha;
}
```

And you also don't need to `@synthesize` each of them anymore, the compiler included with Xcode 5 and up does this for you.

Comment: good point, it has a value 0x7.. and you are right it is there. must just not be displaying it correctly. ty

Comment: as I replied above, po tmpObj returns only that 0x786.. no actual values, so i have to po tmpObj.red ... etc really cumbersome, though everything works but it is really hard to troubleshoot if something goes wrong.

Comment: That's how objects and their properties work... What are you expecting to happen? You can implement `description` so that it prints what you're interested in.

Comment: my point was that just the address was not enough while troubleshooting